# Construction of an isomorphism between Cech's cohomology and singular cohomology

Tags: homology-cohomology, sheaf-cohomology

Given a smooth manifold $M$ and a sheaf $\mathcal{G}$, with $\mathcal{G}(U) = C^{\infty}(U, U(1))$ for open $U \subset M$. I saw that there is an isomorphism

$$H^{1}_{Cech}(M, \mathcal{G}) \simeq H^{2}(M, \mathbb{Z}),$$
between cech cohomology and singular cohomology. How do I build this isomorphism?

Appreciate.

Comment: You want $G = U(1)$ here specifically. One way to describe the map is that it’s given by taking the first Chern class of a line bundle.

Comment: Yep, exactly that case.

Comment: How do I do this construction?

Comment: There is a short exact sequence of sheaves $0\to\mathbb{Z}\to \mathcal{C}^\infty\to\mathcal{G}\to 0$ (where $\mathcal{C}^\infty$ is the sheaf of real valued function and the map $\mathcal{C}^\infty\to\mathcal{G}$ is given by $f\mapsto e^{2i\pi f}$. The long exact sequence of cohomology together with the vanishing of $H^i(M,\mathcal{C}^\infty)$ for $i>0$ ($\mathcal{C}^\infty$ is a fine sheaf) and the isomorphism between Cech and singular cohomology for the constant sheaf gives your isomorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a good open cover, $(U_j)$ ($U_j$ is contractible, a finite intersection of $U_j's$ is contractible), and $g_{jk}:U_j\cap U_k\rightarrow U(1)$, there exist $h_{jk}:U_j\cap U_k\rightarrow \mathbb{R}=Lie(U(1))$ such that $g_{jk}=exp(ih_{jk})$, we have $g_{jk}g_{kl}=g_{jl}$ is equivalent to $exp(ih_{jk})exp(ih_{kl})=exp(i(h_{jk}+h_{kl}))=exp(ih_{jl})$, we deduce that $dh_{jk}$ is a cocycle since the sheaf of $1$-form is fine (there exist partition of unity).
We deduce that there exists $1$-form $h'_{j}$ defined on $U_j$ such that $h'_k-h'_j=h_{jk}$, write $\omega$ the $2$-form whose restriction to $U_j$ is $dh'_j$.

Conversely, consider  a closed $2$-form $\omega$. There exists a $1$-form $h'_j$ defined on $U_j$ such that $dh'_j=\omega_{\mid U_j}$, on $U_{jk}$, we have $dh'_k-dh'_j=0$, this implies there exists a function $h_{jk}$ such that $dh_{jk}=h'_k-h'_j$.   Write $h_{jkl}=h_{kl}-h_{jl}+h_{jk}$ on $U_j\cap U_k\cap U_l$,
$dh_{ijk}=0$, the fact that $\omega$ is a integral form implies that the constant form $h_{jkl}\in\mathbb{Z}$, we can write $g_{jk}=exp(ih_{jk})$ and $g_{jk}g_{kl}=g_{jl}$.